# Dense subset on which continuous map is injective

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This is a follow-on question from: [Dense subset on which quotient map is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849126/dense-subset-on-which-quotient-map-is-injective).

Let $Y$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and $f:Y\to X$ a continuous surjective map. Suppose that each fibre $f^{-1}(x)$ has empty interior and that the density of $Y$ does not exceed $\vert X\vert$. Does $Y$ have a dense subset $D$ which intersects each fibre in at most one point?

**Note:** the linked question shows that the answer is yes if $Y$ is a compact metrisable space. Another case when the answer is yes is when the map $f$ is *irreducible* (that is, no proper closed subset of $Y$ maps onto the whole of $X$). In this case, simply choose a point from each fibre and the resulting set $D$ will be dense.

**Sub-question:** What about the case when $Y$ is separable (but not metrisable)?

**Partial answer to Sub-question:** Suppose that $Y$ is separable and a Frechet-Urysohn space. Inductively define $D$ as follows. Let $\{y_i\}_{i\ge}$ be a countable dense subset for $Y$. Take $D_1=\{ y_1\}$, and for $n>1$, suppose that $D_n$ has been defined consisting of countably many elements of $Y$ from different fibres and such that $y_i\in\overline{D_n}$ $(1\le i\le n)$. If $y_{n+1}$ is from a new fibre, set $D_{n+1}=D_n\cup\{y_{n+1}\}$. Otherwise $y_{n+1}$ lies in the union $W$ of the fibres already chosen. Since fibres have empty interior, $W$ is a countable union of meagre sets and hence meagre, so $y_{n+1}$ lies in the boundary of $W$. By the Frechet-Urysohn property, there is a sequence $(z_i)_{i\ge 1}$ in the complement of $W$ converging to $y_{n+1}$. By omitting from this sequence any term which belongs to the same fibre as a previous term of the sequence, we may assume that the terms come from distinct fibres.
Set $D_{n+1}=D_n\cup \{z_i: i\ge 1\}$, and $D=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} D_n$.

Comment: What is the density of a topological space?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The density $d(X)=\min\{|D||: D \subseteq X\text{ dense in } X\} + \aleph_0$. The last term is to round finite up to $\aleph_0$. So in words: the minimal (infinite) size of a dense subset. $d(X) = \aleph_0$ is saying $X$ is separable.

Comment: If $Y$ has such a subset $D$ that is dense, clearly it follows that $d(Y) \le |D| \le |X|$ so the condition is trivially necessary. The earlier question did not take that into account.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you. I did no know that definition.

Comment: Maybe check the projection $I^\Bbb{N}\to I$, where $I$ is the unit interval

Comment: @Cronus: $I^N$ is a compact metrisable space so it is already covered by the proof in the linked question.

Comment: Really? I only see a counterexample in the linked question...

Comment: I see it now, you wrote it in the question.

Comment: So maybe check $I^I$.

Comment: @Cronus: I don't know much about $I^I$. Is it separable? Is it sequential? Anyway it sounds a good suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it is separable but nowhere first countable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855702/show-that-a-space-is-separable/856096#856096

Comment: Yes it is separable (and not metrizable). Why does it need to be first countable (which indeed it isn't)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113830/discussion-between-user558840-and-cronus).

Comment: I think that the required dense set $D$ exists for the projection from $I^I$ onto $I$.

Comment: Then perhaps you can try to generalize this construction to the general case? Which properties of $I^I$ did you use?

Comment: The construction of the countable dense subset of $I^I$ constructed in the link uses a countable family of intervals and then a countable family of functions on each interval, based on the rationals. But one can partition the rationals into countably many disjoint families of dense subset, and use a different dense family for each interval. So it is more a property of $I$ being used, rather than $I^I$. So far I haven't seen how to extend this.